# My WiFi isn't working

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I've looked at many forums about this issue and none have helped. I can only use Ubuntu 14.04 for the project that I am doing. Currently I can connect to the Internet via Ethernet but i need the WiFi to work also.

- [`wireless info` script results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26091794/)

Results of `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[   11.879152] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   11.879768] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   12.241805] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:05:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   14.727040] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid d82d87d1-cbb3-49ed-bd3b-0ebe99cba661)
[   14.727046] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 (0x05020001, 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 0.0 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   14.727048] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   14.729235] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware register dump:
[   14.729236] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [00]: 0x05020001 0x00000000 0x00A0F776 0x00000000
[   14.729238] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [04]: 0x00A0F776 0x00060130 0x00000010 0xFFFFE000
[   14.729239] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [08]: 0x0042136C 0x00420660 0x00400000 0x00400000
[   14.729240] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [12]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[   14.729241] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [16]: 0x00000002 0x01010101 0x00000003 0x0000000A
[   14.729243] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [20]: 0x00000328 0x00429880 0x009A37AC 0x00000032
[   14.729244] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [24]: 0x800A0D0A 0x0040EA88 0x00420170 0x004173B0
[   14.729245] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [28]: 0x00401F64 0x00401F68 0x00000000 0x00417550
[   14.729246] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [32]: 0x00401FC0 0x5E0CDAF8 0x00403559 0x00000003
[   14.729247] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [36]: 0x800A0907 0x00000001 0x0000085B 0x339011B2
[   14.729248] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [40]: 0x0000FFFE 0x0000000A 0x009BFE28 0x009BE0DC
[   14.729250] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [44]: 0x800A0D0A 0x0040EA88 0x00420170 0x004173B0
[   14.729251] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [48]: 0x00400000 0x00400000 0x00000001 0xFFFFFFFF
[   14.729252] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [52]: 0x800A0614 0x0040EAA8 0x0041FA10 0x00420170
[   14.729253] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [56]: 0x00400000 0x00421370 0x00419980 0x004212E8
[   15.714078] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to receive control response completion, polling..
[   16.714119] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: ctl_resp never came in (-110)
[   16.714124] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to connect to HTC: -110
[   16.714726] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not init core (-110)
[   16.714761] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
[   16.730112] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
[   85.828360] Modules linked in: drbg ansi_cprng cmac bnep rfcomm dm_crypt wl(POE) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev snd_hda_codec_hdmi media snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic ath10k_pci ath10k_core snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dw_dmac_core snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep ath mac80211 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm btusb btrtl btbcm btintel irqbypass bluetooth crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul cfg80211 ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel thinkpad_acpi snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper snd_seq ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq_device snd_timer joydev input_leds nvram serio_raw snd mei_me mei parport_pc soundcore ppdev shpchp tpm_crb mac_hid lp parport i915_bpo psmouse intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper r8169 syscopyarea sdhci_pci sysfillrect sysimgblt sdhci mii fb_sys_fops drm ahci libahci wmi video fjes
[   85.828605]  [<ffffffff8107ea26>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[   85.828614]  [<ffffffff8107eaac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
```

New results of `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[   12.944746] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.945490] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.329526] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:05:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   13.330474] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   13.330477] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   13.330484] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[   13.330485] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
[   13.330490] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
[   13.330492] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[   13.330497] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
[   13.330499] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
[   13.330503] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
[   13.330505] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[   13.330506] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[   13.330508] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
[   80.852019] Modules linked in: drbg ansi_cprng cmac bnep rfcomm dm_crypt uvcvideo wl(POE) videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dw_dmac_core snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp ath10k_pci ath10k_core kvm snd_pcm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel ath mac80211 btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth cfg80211 thinkpad_acpi nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd input_leds joydev serio_raw mei_me mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd tpm_crb parport_pc soundcore shpchp ppdev mac_hid lp parport i915_bpo psmouse r8169 intel_ips i2c_algo_bit mii drm_kms_helper sdhci_pci syscopyarea sdhci sysfillrect ahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops libahci drm wmi video fjes
[   80.852264]  [<ffffffff8107ea26>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[   80.852274]  [<ffffffff8107eaac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
```

Now I think it has something to do with the directories.

here are the new results of : ls -al /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0

```
total 968
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Dec  5 16:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Dec  1 16:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 304308 Sep 12 12:23 board-2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8124 Mar 29  2017 board.bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dec  1 16:04 CNSS.TF.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 605908 Mar 29  2017 firmware-5.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  46142 Mar 29  2017 notice_ath10k_firmware-5.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dec  1 16:04 untested
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dec  1 16:04 WLAN.TF.1.0
```

Comment: Check IP version 4 settings?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath10kpci && dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake! I meant: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath` Please try again.

Comment: For short pastes, please don't use pastebins. Instead, edit your question, paste the text, select the text you just pasted, and press the editor's `{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logs, we see this:

```
[   14.727040] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid d82d87d1-cbb3-49ed-bd3b-0ebe99cba661)
[   14.727046] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 (0x05020001, 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 0.0 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   14.727048] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   14.729235] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware register dump:
[   14.729236] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [00]: 0x05020001 0x00000000 0x00A0F776 0x00000000
```

Let's try more recent firmware. With a working internet connection, open the terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: no improvements

Comment: May we please see: `ls -al /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0`

Comment: i just updated it

Comment: Something has gone very wrong. I just repeated the steps above on my own computer and my hw1.0 directory contains board.bin, board-2.bin, firmware-5.bin and notice_ath10k_firmware-5.txt. You have none of these and `dmesg` confirms that it wants but can't find those very files: "Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2" Did the install go correctly? Were there any errors or warnings? Do you still have the file? Can you try the dpkg -i step again and report back, please?

Comment: i guess they installed correctly this time now what do i do

Comment: Has this changed? `ls -al /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0`? If it contains firmware-5.bin, reboot and see if the wireless works. If not, edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me it worked how can i write a review for you or something

Comment: I'm glad it's working! Your acceptance of my answer is plenty of thanks. Have fun!